# Trajectory execution and environment monitoring

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

We are working in Electric with arm-navigation stack and we would like to know if once the planned trajectory has been sent to execution, an environment monitoring is made. We are worried as the robot surrounding is highly dynamic (the environment changes) and a collision can happen as new objects appear in the planned path. Does the environment server (or any other module of arm-navigation) check for possible collisions during path execution? Or must we check the collision map to detect those possible situations?

On the other hand, we have read that MoveIt! in Groovy implements this path execution checking. Is it a new addition to the arm navigation module?

Thanks in advance,

Ane Fernandez

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59748/trajectory-execution-and-environment-monitoring/) by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-15**:
Phew ! at least another person still on ROS Electric ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ane,

MoveIt! is indeed an advance on Arm Navigation. I would recommend switching over to MoveIt! as we will be able to provide you better support for it.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0